# How do I command vba to start pasting from a specific cell onwards?

Tags: excel, vba

I recently received some great code from one of our fellow users for my copy and paste issue earlier.

This is the help provided after I added in my cell numbers.

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Calculation")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Current")

With sh2

sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sht1.Range("A1448").Value

End With

End Sub
```

I'm currently trying to use it for another sheet, but the challenge is that I would like it to start from row 5 onward as it's a table. Initially, I thought to use:

```
Sheets("Current").Select
Range("A5").Select
```

but no luck. Any advice will be great help on this as the copy and paste code  allows my data collection to run so much faster than before.

Comment: Play around with the `Offset`. Also you are using a explicit sheet reference with a `With` statement. No need to refer to it again. =)

Comment: Hi :), I'm still very green to vba. Could you kindly advise how to use offset in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small example on [`.Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset)

Imagine the following setup:

[image]

You got a specific line of code in your question that will refer to the last used row in a column: `sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)` which normally get followed by `.Row` to refer to a position. Now what `.Offset` does is looking at this position and using an `Index` for both an `Row` and `Column` offset (see documentation) you can refer to another cell, relative to the found cell. (I hope that's clear)

So in the case above, I can put a value in `A7` by writing:

```
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2).Value = "TestValue"
```

[image]

Meaning, to write a value in `A10` I would need to use (if `A7` was still empty):

```
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(5).Value = "TestValue"
```

Comment: Wow that's really great. I noticed that you mentioned that the code will take reference from the last used row (in this case A5). If assuming i have a value copied into A6 using the code. If i run it again (using the same code), will the value be copied to the next available row i.e A7?

Comment: Yes it will @Hanssmith =). Please also don't forget to accept the answer if this has answered your question

Comment: Hi, i tried your code but due to it referring to the last used row in the column, it is skipping the table and pasting the value below it. A1:L1 is a merged cell with a title but A2:L2 is not merged. A4:L4 onwards is where the table starts until A10:L10 but the pasted value comes at the bottom at A11.  Is there any workaround possible?

Comment: @hanssmith, I'm not sure what you are after then. Where do you want the values to be pasted?

Comment: Hi JvdV, what i meant is that the code is skipping my table entirely and pasting the figure on the next empty row outside the table. I would like the value to be pasted inside the table. I've made outlines on my table, could that be a factor?

Comment: @hanssmith an update to your question would be helpful, a picture with how you want your data to be pasted. And what happens now. Visualization is important on this one I guess

Comment: Sure, i have pasted a screenshot of the test code's paste in my table. Hopefully it will help with the explanation.

Comment: I see, you got an actuall table going on then I guess, which will be counted as rows with data. Your table is completely empty, so the easiest for you to do is remove rows from 6 onwards completely. @hanssmith

Comment: does that mean that I will need to manually create the table outlines once my data has been copied over? There's no workaround for this using the code provided?

Comment: @hanssmith, if you use an actual table then the rows will be counted. Otherwise they won't. Maybe to prevent any more communication back and forth, you should share a sample of your workbook so I can take a look

Comment: I'd be happy to! How shall I share it to you? Is the option available on this site?

Comment: No, you'll have to out up a link yourself. There should be some websites that let you share files through a link

Comment: Managed to find some sites but my company's internet keeps blocking them. I'll have to figure this out on my own i guess. But your code earlier and explanation really helped me understand alot about how it works, at least now I have a point to start from. :)

Comment: @hanssmith. Last pointer for you, if you really have a table object. Then look at the clues in the official documentation on a Lustobject. How to refer to them, how to count their rows etc. This was why I wanted to have a look at your file. Tough luck it is blocked hey

Answer (score 0):

JvdV,

This is a screenshot of my test with the suggested code.

[Code test in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooPbT.png)

My aim is to have the figures pasted in the orange row but its skipping the table to paste in the yellow row.